# How can I terminate the input using ctrl+D in Clion on a Mac

Tags: c++, macos

Ctrl+Z used to work well when I wanted to terminate the input in a C++ program on a Windows PC. Now I was writing code on a Mac and I used ctrl+D to simulate the EOF signal, but it behaved weirdly. The input did stop but the program seemed not to continue. The program seemed to have stopped all at once when I pressed ctrl+D. I was writing a simple union find set if that helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "UnionFindSet.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

int n;
int x,y;
std::cin>> n;

UnionFindSet UFSet(n);

while(std::cin>> x >>y)
{
    UFSet.makeUnion(x,y);
}

std::cout<< UFSet.getConnectedPartNumber()<<std::endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: What doesn't work? Looks correct to me.

Comment: The program just stops completely once I pressed ctrl+D, the output statement seems to have been ignored and my breakpoints also failed to work

Comment: I have the same problem. I saw in the settings that on the Mac it's Cmd+D to send EOF, but when I do that my program (different from the OP) stops abruptly without error messages and nothing after that point in the program is executed.

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac CLion maps Ctrl-D to Command-D
Command-D sends an EOF. 
This is configurable under Preferences --> Keymap